# jQuery cycle plugin, customizing the pager tabbing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am working on a mock up site with some functionality. i am working with html css and js. i am using the cycle plugin to cycle through some tabs that i have made up. ill post my code then explain what i am trying to do:

my html:

```
 <div id="content">
  <div id="image_selector" class="image_selector">
    <div class ="image">
      <ul>
        <li><a id="Mpowered" href="">Mpowered</a></li>
        <li><a id="Technology" href="">Technology</a></li>
        <li><a id="Consulting" href="">Consulting</a></li>
        <li><a id="Outsourcing" href="">Outsourcing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
   <div class="description">
      <img id="demoimg" src="/home/***/HTML/launch_pad/images/productivity.png" alt="demo pic"/>
      <h2>Who are we?</h2>
      <p> a consulting company... ect</p>
    </div>


    <div class="description">
      <img id="demoimg" src="/home/***/HTML/launch_pad/images/tech1.jpg" alt="tech"/>
      <h2>We have the tech!</h2>
      <p> lots of tech!!.... ect</p>

    </div>
```

... there are two more description sections one for each of the "a" tags i have now made as tabs.

the css looks like this:

```
.image_selector {
  border: 1px dotted green;
  height: 130px;

}

.image li {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 103px;
  margin-left: 86px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;

}

.image li a {
  padding: 74px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.6em #0197E8;
  font-size: 17px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.image li a:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.6em #0197E8, 0 0 0.4em #0197E8, 0 0 0.6em #0197E8;

}


.image li #Mpowered {
  background-image: url('/home/ruberto/HTML/launch_pad/images/mpower.png');
  background-position: center top; 
}

.image li #Technology {
  background-image: url('/home/ruberto/HTML/launch_pad/images/tech.png'); 
  background-position: center top; 

}

.image li #Consulting {
  background-image: url('/home/ruberto/HTML/launch_pad/images/consulting.png'); 
  background-position: center top; 

}

.image li #Outsourcing {
   background-image: url('/home/ruberto/HTML/launch_pad/images/outsourcing.png'); 
   background-position: center top; 

}

.cell {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  height: 318px;
  width: 715px;
  float: left;

}

#demoimg {
  float: left;
  position: static;
  margin: 16px 8px 0px 0px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;

}
```

and the javascript iam using:

```
$('.cell') 
.before('<div class="image">') 
.cycle({ 
    fx:     'turnDown', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 0, 
    pager:  '.image' 
});
```

so i have read up on line and now understand that the pager option will now create its own navigational section just above the div that has the content that i want to rotate through. i was wondering is there a way i can just reference the "image" tag i have set up as my "tabs" for the navigational function for the cell class??

if there is no way can anyone recommend something that could work in its place?

Comment: try posting a link of your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to reference or even map those li's to other functionality or even build another referencable pager, which what it sounds like you might need to do, you're probably going to need .index to provide a reference for those pair connections.

To start a duplicate pager, clone those elements somewhere else, then maybe simply use css to not display the original, BUT leave it in place so that cycle can use it for paging
    //  create secondary menu
    $('#pager').find('li').clone().appendTo('#navpage ul');

Then if you want to pair your two pagers start with this functionality
http://jsfiddle.net/moneylotion/KhL3W/